# Wordpress search results in modal

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am complete php/js newbie and i got stuck on something that i cant figure out.

I have page at www.test.com/page with a search form that calls www.test.com/results like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.test.com/results">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter URL:" required="">
    <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

Form gets URL that the user typed in, passes it to `/results`, the line `($url  = $_POST['url'];)` is where it is analyzed and results are displayed.

But, i would want the search results to open in (bootstrap) modal instead of new page. I know this can be done with AJAX but i am complete newbie and am looking for most dirty simple solution that would make it work.

Again, sorry if this is too "newbie" type of question, i am still learning.

Comment: First of all, I don't see how you're sending the URL if the `type` attribute is not set. Secondly, I don't think there is a dirty simple solution to do something that is done one way only. So I'd suggest you keep learning and then try to do it again once you've gained more experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use jQuery and AJAX to control the form submit. So something akin to the code example below should do the trick:

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(event) {

    $.post('https://www.test.com/results', { URL: "some_url.com" }, function(data) {
        // Render the results onto your modal anyway you want with data 
        // retrieved from server here
        $("#my-modal-object").html(data);
    }).error(function() {
        // Handle the event when the call to "/results" fails
        alert("Yikes! Call to /results failed!");
    });

    // Prevents default browser behaviour which submits the form 
    // then routes to another page, if specified
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

**Short explanation**:

We attached a `"submit"` event listener to your form object and performed a POST AJAX request to your server endpoint `/results`. Server passes back the processed search results into the callback function of `$.post` and renders it onto your modal object. You may also change the 2nd argument of `$.post`, i.e. `{ URL: "some_url.com" }` to whatever data object you want to pass to your server.

This should help you get started with rendering your search results onto your modal element instead of navigating to a new page.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check-mark! This indicates to the wider community that you've found a possible solution and for further references :)